# xrdp+xfce to install virtual machines in KVM - keyboard does not work

Tags: keyboard, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP DL360. 
This is my test server for my virtulisation platform for testing. 
Thus I configured xrdp+xfce for remote access from my windows laptop. 
So far so good. I am able to remote access my server from my Windows 10 laptop.

Next I started setting up my first ubuntu desktop virtual machine as a test using virt-manager and I use the console from the xrdp+xfce session. I am using KVM+QEMU as my hpyervisor. 
The installation comes to a point where i click next keeping all default options, but now I have to type the username before installation can start and thats where my keyboard does not work. It just basically does not type anything. 
In face I did select my keyboard correctly and it just did not work. 
So I used the virtual keyboard to continue the installation and it worked out ok and I had a workaround to complete the installation. 
Now even to restart I had to manually reset since it does not accept the 'enter' required after removing the cdrom. 
However, now the OS is up in the guest but I cannot log in since I cannot type anything using my windows keyboard when connected from the xrdp session. This means that for each virtual machine I install, I have to go to the server, connect the keyboard, mouse and monitor and do it there to setup the ssh connection and then I can use the virtual machine.

Anyone has any ideas as why is this happening and if there is a way I can connect via xrdp or VNC and not face this issue while installing the Virtual Machines?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue myself, open virtual machine manager, go to edit > preferences > New VM.  For graphics type change from systems default (spice) to VNC.  After doing this you should be able to type in your VM.

[image]